# Can you make a site with ASP.NET MVC Framework using .NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-2.0

Is it possible to make a site with ASP.NET MVC Framework using .NET 2.0?  I am limited to using .NET 2.0 (we use VS 2008, but we have to use the 2.0 Framework) and I really want to try out the MVC Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scott Hanselman described a way to make it work, with some caveats, in his blog:

[Deploying ASP.NET MVC on ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using Visual Studio 2008, but it can cause headaches...

- Create an ASP.NET MVC Web Application
- Set Project Target Framework to 2.0
  in Project Properties
- Add a references to System.Web.MVC (click through warning messages)
- Add any additional references you may need (System.Web.Routing, System.Web.Abstractions) again clicking through any warning messages
- Start coding!
- Not everything you try will work, if you see errors like this on deployment it means that whatever you are doing isn't supported by the 2.0 framework...

  - "The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
- [Configure your IIS](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/06/30/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-6-solve-404-compression-and-performance-problems.aspx) to support MVC Routes and [extensions](http://biasecurities.com/blog/2008/how-to-enable-pretty-urls-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis6/)
- Copy "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core" from the .NET 3.5 development framework to the /bin folder of the IIS Server running .NET 2.0 **SP1**.

Much of this can be found in a lot more detail on [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx)